# Filter edges by property in a subquery - orientdb sql

Tags: database, traversal, graph-databases, orientdb

I have the following OrientDB SQL query that returns the username and country of all the friends of user `#12:0`.

```
select 
   username, country 
from (select 
         expand( both('friends') ) 
      from 
         users 
      where 
         @rid = #12:0)
```

But, the `friends` edge has a property `years` with an integer. I only want those friends of `#12:0` that have `friends.years > 3`.

I have tried

`SELECT username, country from (SELECT expand(outE('friends')[years > 3].inV()) FROM #12:0)`

`SELECT username, country from (SELECT expand(both('friends')[years = 2]) FROM #12:0)`

and various plays on the same query.

Thanks, all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create class User extends V
create property User.username string
create property User.country string

create class friends extends E
create property friends.year integer  


create vertex User content {'username':'u1', 'country':'PT'}
create vertex User content {'username':'f1', 'country':'AW'}
create vertex User content {'username':'f2', 'country':'CN'}

create edge friends 
from (select from User where username = 'u1')
to (select from User where username = 'f1')
content {'years':3}

create edge friends 
from (select from User where username = 'f2')
to (select from User where username = 'u1')
content {'years':4}
```

I believe this is your situation. You can:

```
select expand(bothE('friends')[years = 3].inV()) 
from (select from User where username = 'u1')
```

But, for what I know, the following is not yet supported:

```
select expand(bothE('friends')[years > 3].inV()) 
from (select from User where username = 'u1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to wrap the core query with another nested query:

```
select * from (
select expand(both('friends')) 
from (select from User where username = 'u1')
)
where years > 3
```